# Image Position adjustment

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm telling you briefly what I want, the inputs in the code are on the big image, but I want them to stay in the left corner of the image, I tried many things but I couldn't do it. If we consider 2 columns, the inputs will be on the left, and the largest image will remain fixed on the right.

I have attached the attached image. I have prepared a photo for those who do not understand.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UcEs.png)

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;

  grid-gap: 20px;

  max-width: 100%;
}

.gallery input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.gallery label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.gallery label:before {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  top: -5px;
}

.gallery img {
  display: none;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 8;
  grid-row-end: 8;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
}

.gallery input[name="select"]:checked + label + img {
  display: block;
}

.gallery input[name="select"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* When you mouse over the container, fade in the overlay title */
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
    background: rgb(255 255 255 / 91%);
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="select" id="img-tab-1">
  <label data-title="Sample Infotext" for="img-tab-1" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Orange-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Orange</div></label>

  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Orange-1.jpg" border="0">

  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-2">
  <label for="img-tab-2" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Honey-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Honey</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Honey-1.jpg" border="0">

  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-3">
  <label for="img-tab-3" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Green-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Green</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Green-1.jpg"border="0">
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-4">
  <label for="img-tab-4" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Grape-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Grape</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Grape-1.jpg"border="0">
  
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-13">
  <label for="img-tab-13" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Camel-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Camel</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Camel-1.jpg"border="0">
  
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-19">
  <label for="img-tab-19" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Wine</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg"border="0">
  
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-19">
  <label for="img-tab-19" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Wine</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg"border="0">
  
        <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-28">
  <label for="img-tab-28" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Sky-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Sky</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Sky-1.jpg"border="0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after quite some fiddling with the table grid options I found that the below seems to work.
I myself had to look up some info about the usage of display:grid and found some nice info and examples here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Note that I applied the grid-template-columns property difining 6 columns of equal size that more or less fill the full width. Then I applied some slightly different numbers and spans for the grid-column-start en grid-column-end properties of the .gallery img's defining that the image should take up the 3 columns to the right and also span 3 rows. This makes it so that the labels all take spots in the cells in the left most columns and rows. Giving the below result.

I am aware that the same functionality can be achieved using javascript, which might result in more clean and better readable code, but it was a nice puzzle trying to solve it without.

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 14% 14% 14% 14% 14% 14%;
  grid-gap: 20px;

  max-width: 100%;
}

.gallery input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.gallery label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.gallery label:before {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  top: -5px;
}

.gallery img {
  display: none;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
}

.gallery input[name="select"]:checked + label + img {
  display: block;
}

.gallery input[name="select"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* When you mouse over the container, fade in the overlay title */
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
    background: rgb(255 255 255 / 91%);
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="select" id="img-tab-1" />
  <label data-title="Sample Infotext" for="img-tab-1" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Orange-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Orange</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Orange-1.jpg" border="0" />

  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-2" />
  <label for="img-tab-2" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Honey-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Honey</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Honey-1.jpg" border="0" />

  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-3" />
  <label for="img-tab-3" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Green-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Green</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Green-1.jpg"border="0" />
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-4" />
  <label for="img-tab-4" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Grape-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Grape</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Grape-1.jpg"border="0" />
  
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-13" />
  <label for="img-tab-13" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Camel-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Camel</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Camel-1.jpg"border="0" />
  
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-19" />
  <label for="img-tab-19" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Wine</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg"border="0" />
  
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-19" />
  <label for="img-tab-19" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Wine</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg"border="0" />
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-28" />
  <label for="img-tab-28" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Sky-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Sky</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Sky-1.jpg"border="0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're amazing, exactly what I wanted :) thank you, I love this platform..

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 14% 14% 14% 14% 14% 14%;
  grid-gap: 20px;

  max-width: 100%;
}

.gallery input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.gallery label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.gallery label:before {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  top: -5px;
}

.gallery img {
  display: none;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: span 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 150ms linear;
}

.gallery input[name="select"]:checked + label + img {
  display: block;
}

.gallery input[name="select"]:checked + label:before {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* When you mouse over the container, fade in the overlay title */
.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
    background: rgb(255 255 255 / 91%);
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="select" id="img-tab-1" />
  <label data-title="Sample Infotext" for="img-tab-1" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Orange-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Orange</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Orange-1.jpg" border="0" />

  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-2" />
  <label for="img-tab-2" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Honey-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Honey</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Honey-1.jpg" border="0" />

  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-3" />
  <label for="img-tab-3" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Green-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Green</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Green-1.jpg"border="0" />
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-4" />
  <label for="img-tab-4" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Grape-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Grape</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Grape-1.jpg"border="0" />
  
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-13" />
  <label for="img-tab-13" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Camel-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Camel</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Camel-1.jpg"border="0" />
  
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-19" />
  <label for="img-tab-19" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Wine</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg"border="0" />
  
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-19" />
  <label for="img-tab-19" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Wine</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Wine-3.jpg"border="0" />
  
  <input type="radio" name="select" id="img-tab-28" />
  <label for="img-tab-28" style="background-image: url(http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Sky-1.jpg);"><div class="overlay">Sky</div></label>
  <img src="http://www.wphizmetleri.com/felt/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Pet-Felt-Panel-Acoustic-Sky-1.jpg"border="0" />
</div>
```